# Does target designation override what targets are normally valid for a missile/rocket?

Tags: battlefield-3

If I'm flying a helicopter, there is an unlock that allows me to Laser-Designate ("Paint a Target") to be fired on by guided missiles.  I am able to paint many targets, such as enemy armor, enemy equipment, and even enemy aircraft (planes/helicopters).

My gunner is equipped with an Air-To-Ground Guided Missile.  Normally, he can lock onto ground targets, such as armor and equipment, and fire the missile at them.  However, he also is capable of locking his missile onto targets that others have painted.

Is it possible in this case for the gunner to lock his missile onto planes/helicopters, even though he cannot normally lock these targets, assuming that they have been properly painted by myself in the piloting role?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with laser designation aircraft can be targeted by weapons which normally lock on ground vehicles and equipment:

- Javelin
- Guided Shell (tank upgrade)
- Guided Rockets (heli upgrade)

As a side note, MAV even though it's airborne, is considered equipment, not air vehicle. So you can down it with guided missiles even without laser designation.

Example with tank guided shell: